# How to find the intersecting corners from a set of line segments

Tags: geometry

I have a list of end-points of a line segment as {(p1, p2), (p1, p2), ...} where each p is (x, y) coordinate. The set of lines does not contain only 4 elements, but more within 1-5 points of uncertainty along each coordinate.

I do know that they form a quadrilateral, more precisely kind of a parallelogram (I say this because I am getting line information from the image and the original image is a parallelogram, but by doing some image processing, the results are skewed a little, so let's just say it is a quadrilateral). How would I go about finding the corners of the enclosing quadrilateral?

**Edit**:
The list contains pairs of ordered pairs.

Here is one example:

```
 {p1: (20, 47), p2: (67, 35)}, 
 {p1: (8, 22), p2: (65, 7)}, 
 {p1: (10, 49), p2: (65, 36)}, 
 {p1: (8, 47), p2: (9, 20)}, 
 {p1: (11, 20), p2: (54, 9)}, 
 {p1: (9, 48), p2: (37, 42)},
 {p1: (32, 16), p2: (62, 8)}, 
 {p1: (9, 47), p2: (8, 23)}, 
 {p1: (67, 34), p2: (68, 13)},
 {p1: (68, 33), p2: (67, 9)}
```

Comment: Is it “kind of” a parallelogram, or is it *actually* a parallelogram?

Comment: Is your list a list of ordered pairs, or list of pairs of ordered pairs?
If its the second, start by searching for sets of pairs of ordered pairs that share a common ordered pair.

Comment: This questions is very unclear.

Comment: Are you looking for a convex hull calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the line joining two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is

$$ a x + b y + c = 0 $$
$$ (y_1-y_2) x + ( x_2-x_1) y + ( x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1 ) =0 $$

And the point that two lines $a x + b y + c =0$ and $d x + e y + f =0$ meet is

$$ x =  \frac{b f - c e}{a e - b d} $$
$$ y = \frac{ c  d - a f}{a e-b d} $$

You can work out the rest yourself.